# Hibernate 4 -> 5 upgrade leads to LazyInitializationException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, lazy-initialization

I upgraded a project from Spring 4.3.9.RELEASE + Hibernate 4.3.11.Final to Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE and Hibernate 5.3.9.Final. The queries are still working fine, but I'm getting `LazyInitializationException` with some `@OneToMany` class members.

First I retrieve the object, which has a reference to a `@OneToMany` List, from the `@Transaction` service. The collection is returned to the controller, and from there it goes back to Spring to be serialized into a json. The controller has `@RestController`, so it knows what to do.

In Spring 4.3.9.RELEASE + Hibernate 4.3.11.Final everything was fine, even though `OpenEntityManagerInView` wasn't enabled by configuration and the collection wasn't loaded with EAGER mode. But in Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE and Hibernate 5.3.9.Final the same thing doesn't work anymore. I've tried enabling OEMIV, by setting `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`, but even this doesn't seem to work or it's being overriden somewhere.

If I enable EAGER loading mode for that collection, everything works fine.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

@Entity
@JsonSerialize(using = TemplateSerializer.class)
public class Template implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private ObjFormat objFormat;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Event event;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private List<Category> linkToCategories;
```

The problem is caused by field linkToCategories. If I configure    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) everything works fine.

Application configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
              localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.project.backend.model",
            "com.project.backend.hibernate.converters");
        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }
```

Later edit:
After a lot of debugging, the difference between the old and the new Hibernate functionality is in the HibernateTransactionManager. In the method doGetTransaction(), in Hibernate 4 it finds the SessionHolder object when calling

> TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(getSessionFactory())

while in Hibernate 5 it doesn't.

> ```
>     SessionHolder sessionHolder =
>             (SessionHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(getSessionFactory());
>     if (sessionHolder != null) {
>         if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
>             logger.debug("Found thread-bound Session [" + sessionHolder.getSession() + "] for Hibernate transaction");
>         }
>         txObject.setSessionHolder(sessionHolder);
>     }
>     else if (this.hibernateManagedSession) {
>         try {
>             Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
>             if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
>                 logger.debug("Found Hibernate-managed Session [" + session + "] for Spring-managed transaction");
>             }
>             txObject.setExistingSession(session);
>         }
>         catch (HibernateException ex) {
>             throw new DataAccessResourceFailureException(
>                     "Could not obtain Hibernate-managed Session for Spring-managed transaction", ex);
>         }
>     }
> ```

In the method doBegin, a new session is created and set on the txObject for every request.

```
        if (txObject.getSessionHolder() == null || txObject.getSessionHolder().isSynchronizedWithTransaction()) {
            Interceptor entityInterceptor = getEntityInterceptor();
            Session newSession = (entityInterceptor != null ?
                    getSessionFactory().withOptions().interceptor(entityInterceptor).openSession() :
                    getSessionFactory().openSession());
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Opened new Session [" + newSession + "] for Hibernate transaction");
            }
            txObject.setSession(newSession);
        }
```

My experience with Hibernate is fairly small, so here I'm stuck. It's probably a configuration thing, but I can't find it.

Comment: So you are upgrading from 4.3 (Spring) to 5.1 (2 major versions), hibernate you go up 4 versions, move from a Spring application to a Spring Boot application. Aren't you simply doing too much in one go? You are using hibernate but are you doing JPA or plain Hibernate. You don't show code that fails nor configuration.

Comment: It's not the first Spring Boot upgrade, so nothing to where there. Hibernate 5.3.9.Final comes with the Spring Boot, so I didn't downgrade to a previous version. I will consider that, thank you. Regarding the code, I didn't add it because it's easy to explain. I will do some modifications now.

Comment: You are using plain hibernate NOT jpa so enabling the `OpenEntityManagerInView` will ofcourse not help. Judging from your question you are going from a regular Spring application to Spring Boot.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I'm transitioning to Spring Boot. I've done this before, but I didn't have Hibernate included.

Comment: Just did a test with Hibernate 5.0.3.Final, and the result is the same. Regarding the configuration, I didn't do anything else than to move it from config file to code.

Comment: You are moving from hibernate4 to 5, make sure you use the proper infrastructure. Also as mentioned you are using Hibernate NOT plain JPA.

Comment: What do you mean by the proper infrastructure? Everything works fine, the only problem is this lazy loading.

Comment: The correct Spring classes for Hibernate 5 and as mentioned twice by now, the OpenEntituyManager stuff won't help as you are using plain hibernate NOT jpa. You need an OpenSessionInView instead. However I would strongly suggest to ditch plain Hibernate in favor of JPA. Also as stated you are moving from a plain Spring application to Spring BOot so there are probably some additional filters in the web.xml or `WebApplicationInitializer` used for bootstrapping the application, which you haven't configured/copied.

Comment: I will try to enforce this again. The application works fine after the transition to Spring Boot. The database queries also work very well. The previous version used Hibernate, now it's still Hibernate. The only problem is related to the EAGER collections but I don't understand how it worked with Hibernate 4.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the hibernate version. But with the other components configiured in the plain Spring application as opposed to the Spring Boot application. As stated I suspect there was an `OpenSessionInViewFilter` or `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` configured in your Spring application. You haven't ported this to the Spring Boot one and hence this fails.

Comment: There is only one constant in Hibernate upgrades: with every upgrade you learn new things that you were always doing wrong. Older versions of Hibernate were quite forgiving, newer versions are quite strict.

Comment: You were correct, finally I managed to check that OpenSessionInViewFilter was configured and it's not configured in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As M. Deinum was saying, the Spring 4.3.9.RELEASE + Hibernate 4.3.11.Final configuration was loading OpenSessionInViewFilter, which explains why all the queries were going through successfully. After configuring the same filter in Spring Boot, everything is back to normal. Add the following bean to register the filter:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<OpenSessionInViewFilter> registerOpenSessionInViewFilterBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<OpenSessionInViewFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    OpenSessionInViewFilter filter = new OpenSessionInViewFilter();
    registrationBean.setFilter(filter);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

The next step is to replace plain Hibernate with JPA, and OpenSessionInViewFilter with OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.

Thanks M. Deinum.

Answer (score 0):

`@xxxToMany` annotations inicates that fetch type is `LAZY` by default. It means that you need to initialize collection your entity refers to.

Eg.

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @OneToMany
    public List<Author> authors;    

}
```

There is few ways to resolve this. You can modify `@OneToMany` annotation with:

```
@OneToMany(FetcType=FetchType.EAGER)
```

Or to make a method where you will initialize `authors` eg.:

```
public void initializeAuthors(Book book) {

    Book b = em.find(Book.class, book.getId());
    List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>(b.getAuthors());

    book.setAuthors(authors);

}
```

If you have `@NamedQueries` on your entities, you can do that by adding `LEFT JOIN FETCH` on your collections.

Comment: I know what you mean, but identical code works just fine in Spring 4.3.9.RELEASE + Hibernate 4.3.11.Final.

Comment: Eager fetching oneToMany collections is not exactly a good idea, there is a good reason they are lazy by default. This may well cause a bombardment of queries to be invoked depending on how large the collection is. The fetch join is a good performant suggestion though.

Comment: For now there's not enough time to rework the entire repository layer, so I have to stick with what's given. In the future, optimizing Hibernate and the integration is the next logical step.

Comment: @Gimby Agree that EAGER fetch type is not good idea. Initialization of relations when you need it is much better idea. I described it in my answer.